# ElasticSearch: Can I get a score relative to the entire index but only retrieve documents that pass a filter in one search call?

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

Currently, I am making two search calls:

1. The first search is without any filters, I capture the top X results and save their scores
2. The second search includes the filters, and I recalculate the scores for the resulting documents relatively to the top scores I got from my first search.

The result is the filtered documents with their relative scores. Is it possible to do this in one go?

Filtering removes the better-scoring documents, and I need their scores as an anchor for the remaining documents.